# Unable to open datasource `GeoJSON' with the following drivers

Tags: geojson

I am trying to follow the tutorial at this link http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/
I have followed every instruction exactly as listed so far but when I try to run the command found in the "#Converting Data" section to create the subunits.json file:

```
$ogr2ogr \ -f GeoJSON \ -where "ADM0_A3 IN ('GBR', 'IRL')" \ subunits.json \   ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
```

I get the following error (others posted about a similar error where the existing file ne_10m_admin... could not be opened but I can't find anything on the GeoJSON issue below):

```
$ ogr2ogr \ -f GeoJSON \ -where "ADM0_A3 IN ('GBR', 'IRL')" \ subunits.json \   ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp

FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `GeoJSON' with the following drivers.
-> ESRI Shapefile
-> MapInfo File
-> UK .NTF
-> SDTS
-> TIGER
-> S57
-> DGN
-> VRT
-> REC
-> Memory
-> BNA
-> CSV
-> GML
-> GPX
-> KML
-> GeoJSON
-> GMT
-> GPKG
-> SQLite
-> WAsP
-> PCIDSK
-> OpenFileGDB
-> XPlane
-> AVCBin
-> AVCE00
-> DXF
-> Geoconcept
-> GeoRSS
-> GPSTrackMaker
-> VFK
-> PGDump
-> OSM
-> GPSBabel
-> SUA
-> OpenAir
-> PDS
-> WFS
-> HTF
-> AeronavFAA
-> EDIGEO
-> GFT
-> GME
-> SVG
-> CouchDB
-> Idrisi
-> ARCGEN
-> SEGUKOOA
-> SEGY
-> XLS
-> ODS
-> XLSX
-> ElasticSearch
-> PDF
-> CartoDB
-> SXF
```

Comment: you may consider posting this in the [Geographic Information System](http://gis.stackexchange.com) forum

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56652/how-to-move-and-open-shapefiles-with-ogr2ogr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue. It was a result of the topojson installation. Originally I installed with the command:
`sudo npm install -g topojson`
(also tried uninstalling and reinstalling with this command just incase)

Finally I uninstalled and reinstalled with the command:
`sudo -H npm install -g topojson`

Answer (score 4):

The instructions are a little unclear in the tutorial. You need to click the links:

Admin 0 - Details - map subunits
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.zip

Populated Places
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_populated_places.zip

Unzip those files

unzip FILE_NAME

- Should produce .dbf, .prj, .shp, .shx, and .cpg files

And then run the command:

ogr2ogr   -f GeoJSON   -where "ADM0_A3 IN ('GBR', 'IRL')"   subunits.json   ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp